# How to update table with dynamic table name?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update table columns which is generated dynamically.

I tried this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]
     @Id INT ,
     @Flag varchar(MAX),
     @TableName nvarchar(max) ,  
AS  
BEGIN    
    IF(@Flag='Process')  
    BEGIN   
    DECLARE @squery nvarchar(max) = ''

    IF EXISTS(SELECT NAME FROM [DZ_REPO].SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = @TABLENAME)
        BEGIN
            set @squery = 'use [DZ_REPO]'
            set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cFirstName=B.FN, A.cLastName=B.LN, A.cAddress=B.ADDR, A.cCity=B.CITY, A.cState=B.ST, A.cZIP=B.ZIP, 
            A.cGender=B.GENDER, A.cAge=B.EXACT_AGE, A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.HH_INCOME FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [Consumer].[dbo].[CONSUMERDB] as B 
            WHERE A.Email=B.Email AND A.AccountId =('+ @Id+')'          
            print (@squery)

            set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cGender=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cGender=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=N'Gender' AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

            UPDATE A SET A.cHouseholdIncome=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=('+HouseholdIncome+')  AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

            UPDATE A SET A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=('+PresenceOfChild+') AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')'
        END
    END  
END
```

But it gives error stating that

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 6 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   spFileProcess, Line 26 Incorrect syntax near 'Gender'. Msg 102, Level
>   15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 48 Incorrect syntax near
>   'False'

I edit by

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]
     @Id INT = 1 ,
     @Flag varchar(MAX) = 'Process',
     @TableName nvarchar(max) = 'SONY'  
AS  
BEGIN    
    IF(@Flag='Process')  
    BEGIN   
    DECLARE @squery nvarchar(max) = ''
    print ('call')
    IF EXISTS(SELECT NAME FROM [DZ_REPO].SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = @TABLENAME)
        BEGIN
            set @squery = 'use [DZ_REPO]'
            print (@squery)
            set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cFirstName=B.FN, A.cLastName=B.LN, A.cAddress=B.ADDR, A.cCity=B.CITY, A.cState=B.ST, A.cZIP=B.ZIP, 
            A.cGender=B.GENDER, A.cAge=B.EXACT_AGE, A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.HH_INCOME FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [Consumer].[dbo].[CONSUMERDB] as B 
            WHERE A.Email=B.Email AND A.AccountId =('+ @Id+')'          
            print (@squery)

            set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cGender=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cGender=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=N'Gender' AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

            UPDATE A SET A.cHouseholdIncome=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=('+HouseholdIncome+')  AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

            UPDATE A SET A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=('+PresenceOfChild+') AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')'
        END
    END  
END
```

but no one print is call and error throw folling

**Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 28
Invalid column name 'Gender'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 30
Invalid column name 'HouseholdIncome'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 32
Invalid column name 'PresenceOfChild'.**

although this coumn is already in mt table

Any solution?

Comment: what is your error, pls post it in your question

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'Gender'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 48
Incorrect syntax near 'False'.

Comment: Can you please show the schema for both tables A and B. It seems to me that requisite columns doesn't exist in either table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need space between First Update statement and second Update statement.

```
...A.AccountId =('+ @Id+')' and set @squery += 'UPDATE A....
```

It should be changed to

```
...A.AccountId =('+ @Id+')' and set @squery += ' UPDATE A...
```

It will be easy to debug if you `print` before the `dynamic Sql execution`. You are printing the `@squery` in middle, even after that you are appending Update statements so its better to `print` and check after appending all the `update statements`.

Also varchar column values should be enclosed with `single quotes`.

Make sure you pass **values** to all the `variables` else you `@squery` will be `NULL`

```
set @squery = 'use [DZ_REPO]'

set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cFirstName=B.FN, A.cLastName=B.LN, A.cAddress=B.ADDR, A.cCity=B.CITY, A.cState=B.ST, A.cZIP=B.ZIP, 
            A.cGender=B.GENDER, A.cAge=B.EXACT_AGE, A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.HH_INCOME FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [Consumer].[dbo].[CONSUMERDB] as B 
            WHERE A.Email=B.Email AND A.AccountId =('+ @Id+')'          
            print (@squery)

 set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cGender=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B 
                WHERE A.cGender=B.[Key] 
                AND B.[Column]=N'''Gender''' --Here
                AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

 UPDATE A SET A.cHouseholdIncome=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B 
 WHERE A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.[Key] 
 AND B.[Column]=('''+HouseholdIncome+''')  
 AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

 UPDATE A SET A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B 
 WHERE A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Key] 
 AND B.[Column]=('''+PresenceOfChild+''') --here
 AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')'
```

Comment: When i execute after editing suggested by you i got error like this, "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'Gender'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spFileProcess, Line 48
Incorrect syntax near 'False'."

Comment: Put the print statement before dynamic exexution which also not printed

Comment: @KinjalPatel Make sure you pass **values** to all the `variables` else you `@squery` will be `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I think u need add space in you query string like this

```
set @squery = 'use [DZ_REPO] '
set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cFirstName......'
```

And remove , after `@TableName nvarchar(max)`

Answer (score 0):

**First Error:** Remove comma(,) from end of @TableName nvarchar(max) variable.
**Second Error:** You need to declare Gender, HouseholdIncome, HouseholdIncome, PresenceOfChild, if you are passing some dynamic values on it. or if this if column name then remove + (plus) from it.

ex:
*AND B.[Column]=(HouseholdIncome)*

Comment: I will try like this and getting error like  "**Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'use [DZ_REPO] UPDATE A SET A.cFirstName=B.FN, A.cLastName=B.LN, A.cAddress=B.ADDR, A.cCity=B.CITY, A.cState=B.ST, A.cZIP=B.ZIP, 
   A.cGender=B.GENDER, A.cAge=B.EXACT_AGE, A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.HH_INCOME FROM [dbo].[SONY] as A, [Consumer].[dbo].[CONSUMERDB] as B 
   WHERE A.Email=B.Email AND A.Picked IS NULL AND A.DataProfilingAccountId =('+ @Id+')' to data type int.**"

Comment: Use this  A.DataProfilingAccountId =( @Id)

Answer (score 0):

Check this sql with comment (this is your first sql post) :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spname]
     @Id INT ,
     @Flag varchar(MAX),
     @TableName nvarchar(max),  --remove comma from here
AS  
BEGIN    
    IF(@Flag='Process')  
    BEGIN   
    DECLARE @squery nvarchar(max) = ''

    IF EXISTS(SELECT NAME FROM master.SYS.TABLES WHERE NAME = @TABLENAME)
        BEGIN
            set @squery = 'use [DZ_REPO]'
            set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cFirstName=B.FN, A.cLastName=B.LN, A.cAddress=B.ADDR, A.cCity=B.CITY, A.cState=B.ST, A.cZIP=B.ZIP, 
            A.cGender=B.GENDER, A.cAge=B.EXACT_AGE, A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.HH_INCOME FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [Consumer].[dbo].[CONSUMERDB] as B 
            WHERE A.Email=B.Email AND A.AccountId =('+ @Id+')'          
            print (@squery)

            --if 'Gender' id your fixed column then give as below with double comma
            --HouseholdIncome - where you define this variable and assign it
            --PresenceOfChild - where you define this variable and assign it
            set @squery += 'UPDATE A SET A.cGender=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cGender=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=N''Gender'' AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

            UPDATE A SET A.cHouseholdIncome=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cHouseholdIncomeCode=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=('+HouseholdIncome+')  AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')

            UPDATE A SET A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Value] FROM [dbo].['+@TableName+'] as A, [dbo].[abc] as B WHERE A.cPresenceOfChild=B.[Key] AND B.[Column]=('+PresenceOfChild+') AND A.AccountId = ('+@Id+')'
        END
    END  
END
```